# Pydev, eclipse and pythonpath problem

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've installed pydev to my eclipse 3.5.2. Everything was working smoothly, create projects, execute, test, autocomplete.

But then I realized that importing modules from /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6, such as django, causes error "Unresolved import: xxxx". Of course, PYTHONPATH SYSTEM includes the directories I want. What's more, inside package explorer i can c the modules under "System Libs".

I just can't import them :S. Is this a bug? Or I just missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: I had to add libs as folders using project properties dialog. Not a clean solution sure, but I can work for now.

Project properties -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH -> External Libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using virtualenv you should setup an interpreter using the python build inside.

ie., default python interpreter for th project will be /usr/bin/python

but change it to something like "{project name} python" and point it to your virtual env path.  In my case it's ~/.virtualenvs/acme/bin/python

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse you can add django folder in you python path.

Window->Preferences-> PyDev-> Interpreters->Python Interpreter -> Lirararies -> New Folder

And browse till the parent folder of modules you are searching.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some sort of cache issue in PyDev... in which case you could try to remove the interpreter, add it again and restart Eclipse.